# How to create a week, month, year summary of a database

Tags: mysql, extract, summary

I want to create an application which one is summary the values of each column. I have a table like this:

Each rows contains one goods

```
Date      | Company_Name | Order_cost | Weight |
2013-05-15| Dunaferr     | 310        | 1200   |
2013-05-18| Pentele      | 220        | 1600   |
2013-05-25| Dunaferr     | 310        | 1340   |
```

and what I exactly need is a table or view which contains the totals for the weights column for each week which is supposed to be extracted from the date column!

Something like that

```
company_name | week1 | week2  | week3 | week4 ...
dunaferr     | 35000 | 36000  | 28000 | 3411
pentele      | 34000 | 255000 | 3341  | 3433
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer, e.g. with a simple php loop acting on an ordered array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two steps:

First step complete an sql query getting a summary with a sum for weight with a group by for yearweek

```
SELECT Company_Name, YEARWEEK(Date), sum(weight) FROM table GROUP BY Company_Name, YEARWEEK(Date)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek.

Second step would be to process this into the required format in the application year.

If you absolutely have to do this in the database, then you are looking at implementing a pivot table, which has previously been covered here: [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: is there any way to do it more dynamic couse i need to generete it from thousands of rows and its not an option to write the transfer line by line.